# JavaScript + index Of returns false when should be true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

I do not know what I am doing wrong when checking if a piece of text exists within a string.
When the text I look for is present, my check seems to not see it and sends the code to the else part of the statement.

the code in question:

```
if (response.data.indexOf("Panelists sucessfully added Meeting ID") > 0) { < this check
    $scope.IsColor = true;
    $scope.Messages = response.data;
    angular.element("#msg").focus()
    return true;
}
else {
    $scope.IsColor = false;
    $scope.Messages = response.data;
    angular.element("#msg").focus()
    return false;
}
```

The contents of response.data

```
response.data[0]: "Panelists sucessfully added Meeting ID: 94395753143 on 07/31/2020 at 01:53:17 PM"
```

Screenshot:

[image: response.data]

Is it because indexOf cannot be used to check if a value exists within a string in an array?

Any insight is appreciated.

Thank you,
Erasmo

Comment: `indexOf` returns `-1` for not found.  So `> 0` would not allow you to match against the first element

Comment: It returns `0` and you are checking `> 0`. The condition should be `>= 0` or `> -1`

Comment: `response.data[0].indexOf()` otherwise your doing an indexOf an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const response = 'Panelists sucessfully added Meeting ID: 94395753143 on 07/31/2020 at 01:53:17 PM';

if (response.indexOf('Panelists sucessfully added Meeting ID') !== -1) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```